# Face detection ,Identify real human or human from playing video

Tags: face-detection, google-vision

I am using **Google Vision** for **facial detection**, everything works fine but we have to know that if we are actually detecting actual **Human**, One may try to play the **video containing a Human** so we want to know if it is from **video/Image** or an original **human being** ?
Is there any way to **achieve** it, I have search throughout for 2 days and did not get any lead on this, **please guide** me through this **thanks**.

Comment: if you have a video/image of (a person playing a video of someone's face), it'll be hard to use the API to figure out which one is the person and which one is the video

Comment: yes,   exactly, I am trying to check it using certain instruction and response of that instruction, if a user behaves then we can conclude it is actual human as videos could be pre-captured, what you say @Torry Yang

Comment: this is not possible with the vision api right now